# java arguments String[] args cannot be accepted by the function

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] test={"O","X","O","X","#","O","X","O","_","_","_","_","Y"};
    Tic(test);
    Tic(args);
}
```

When I use the command line to give the arguments : O X O X # O X O _ _ _ _ Y

They are supposed to be the same, but the later one returns a null solution.
My algorithm is to implement some kinds of game theory.I use several recursions in the Tic function. 
In this main method, when I use the test I can get my solutions. However, since args is also type of String[], when I want to do Tic(args), it will not do the recursion at all and will get a null result.
I try to fix it with transfer the args to a new String[]. But nothing works. I check the input of the function and find no error.

Comment: Can you show us the Tic code?

Comment: How do you run the application with those command-line arguments?

Comment: Would you also get the solutions if you run it multiple times in a row with just `test`? Maybe it's stateful?

Comment: @Brunaldo it is kind of long, it is a alpha-beta pruning playing tictactoe.

Comment: @Makoto java TicTacToe O X O X # O X O _ _ _ _ Y

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool it do work since I can change the test sample to get every answers.

Comment: @Brunaldo http://ideone.com/rbG6O7 I hope this link will work

Comment: Why don't you do a sysout on the test and args arrays using Arrays.toString to see if they differ

Answer (score 0):

Try this when passing it as an argument:

```
javac YourJavaFileName.java
```

and then

```
java YourJavaFileName O X O X '#' O X O _ _ _ _ Y
```

The hashkey is stopping the rest of the line to be read into args array, and hence I add single quotes around it.

Edit:
After further input from @Andreas :

- Anything after the # is treated as a comment in Unix based systems
  and hence it's not read into the args. This does not happen happen in
  Windows OS however.

Comment: My *Windows* command prompt have no problem with `#`. I believe your answer is probably the right answer, but it assumes an OS not in evidence.

Comment: Strange. I'm on Mac OS and without the single quotes this is what gets passed: [O, X, O, X] , with the single quotes this is what gets passed: [O, X, O, X, #, O, X, O, _, _, _, _, Y]

Comment: Not strange at all, because `#` is the start of a *comment* in most Linux shells, and why I think your answer is the right one. The Windows command prompt does not use `#` for comments, so your answer is only applicable to Linux OS's (incl. Mac), and you should clarify that in the answer. You might even want to clarify *why*, i.e. the fact that `#` makes the rest of a line be a comment.

Comment: Actually I am using a Windows OS, as far as I can do in my test, I can see the # was taken in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, I use the == to represent the equality of value, that is actually the reference. When I replace == with String.equal() the args can be passed correctly. I am very new in java sorry for the dumb question.